# Set breakpoint on specific line using LLDB

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints, lldb

I am attempting to set a breakpoint on line 37 of my project in Xcode and I want to set this using LLDB. I know that I can set this breakpoint manually by clicking in the gutter, but I want to gain a better understanding of using LLDB. How would I build off of the statement below? Is that statement even heading in the correct direction?

```
breakpoint set --file
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reference the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-command-examples.html)

It looks like you can set a breakpoint in a particular file and line by using

```
(lldb) breakpoint set --file test.c --line 12
```

Comment: There's also the shorter syntax:
`(lldb) b test.c:12`