# LLDB: No selected frame to use to find the default file. No file supplied and no default file available

Tags: c, debugging, clang, lldb

I've made a "Hello World!" C file called `a.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("Hello World!");

    return 0;
}
```

To compile I run

```
clang -g a.c -o a.exe
```

To debug I run

```
C:\folder>lldb a.exe
Current executable set to 'C:\folder\a.exe' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
```

I then try to put a breakpoint on line 5 with

```
(lldb) b 5
```

but I get

```
(lldb) b 5
error: No selected frame to use to find the default file.
error: No file supplied and no default file available.
(lldb)
```

When I am explicit and specify the file to put the breakpoint I get

```
(lldb) b a.c:5
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
(lldb)
```

Why is this happening? Is the debug information missing from the binary?

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set breakpoint on specific line using LLDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555329/set-breakpoint-on-specific-line-using-lldb)

Comment: @JeffHolt As far as I can tell that output is normal

Comment: @EugeneSh. It doesn't seem to want to accept that the file exists

Comment: Are you sure it is counting the empty lines?  Try line 1 instead.

Comment: Maybe your .dSYM folder is where the debugging information is stored and that folder is not being written to the place where lldb is looking?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Same happens with line 1, and every other line.

Comment: @JeffHolt Where is the default location for the .dSYM folder? I can't find it in my working directory...

Comment: Normally, you'd find .dSYM alongside the output executable. But that's only if clang is supposed to write it to the .dSYM folder.

Comment: @JeffHolt All I have are the source, executable, ILK, and PDB. I think it must be something wrong with clang because it occurs with every program I compile

Comment: Maybe you can work around the problem if youcompile to .o first and then link: `clang -c -g *.c; clang -g -o a.exe *.o`.

Comment: If there's a separate debug file, the output of `image list a.exe` should show two entries, one for the path to a.exe and one for the path to the PDB.  That's what it does on macOS  but I'm pretty sure it works that way on Windows as well.  Does this show the PDB file?  If not you could try `target symbols add <PATH TO PDB>`.  I don't know how lldb locates PDB's on Windows, but maybe that's failing?

Comment: @JeffHolt Same result, unfortunately. I'm going to try using an older version of clang to see if it's just a problem with the latest version, and if not I'll open an issue with LLVM.

Comment: @JimIngham `image list a.exe` only shows the entry for the executable, and `target symbols add` gives `error: symbol file 'C:\folder\a.pdb' does not match any existing module`. It's definitely generated by clang each time I compile though, I don't see how it doesn't match a.exe.

Comment: Apparently, LLDB doesn't even support 64-bit Windows, and LLVM as a whole is just meh with Windows. I'll use VS until I fully move to Linux, thanks for the help though.